# openCV load image with type CV_8UC4

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to load image of any possible supported type and convert it to BGRA (CV_8UC4).

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string filePath;
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    std::cout << "HEIGHT: "  << image.rows << " Width: " << image.cols << std::endl;
    std::cout << "CHANNELS: "  << image.channels() << std::endl;

    switch(image.channels())
    {
        case 1:
        {
            cvtColor(image, image, CV_GRAY2BGRA);
            std::cout << "CHANNELS: "  << image.channels() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
            std::cout << "CHANNELS: "  << image.channels() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    switch(image.depth())
    {
        case CV_8U:
        {
            /* DO NOTHING AS IT IS DESIRED */
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            image.convertTo(image, CV_8U);
            image.depth() == CV_8U ? std::cout << "CONVERSION SUCCESSFUL" << std::endl : std::cout << "CONVERSION UNSUCCESSFUL" << std::endl;
        }
    }
cv::resize(image, image, cvSize(1920, 1080));
/*************Now do desired operations*******************/
}
```

Just want to make sure if there is no condition missing. Can you please check if for some type of image this may fail to give me CV_8UC4 image??

Please suggest if there is any better approach possible.

******Edit*******

I was able to achieve the above. But now I am facing another problem

I need to operate on images with size less than 1920x1080 so when I load the image, I resize it to smaller size.
The problem I am facing is with images of very large resolution (since I can use just 500 mb of memory but the allocation size of cv::Mat is exceeding that. Therefore even when I have to operate on scaled image (smaller resolution) I cannot load the original image before resizing.

Is there an option to scale the image while loading so that cv::Mat uses memory according to the scaled version of the image?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `cv::imread(width, height, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);` wouldn't have even [compiled](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#Mat%20imread(const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags)).

Comment: please suggest the correct approach to get 8bit depth and 4 channels after loading

Comment: In which sense does this "not work"? Please elaborate, and ideally show us an expected vs. actual result. | Also note that when using `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` "the alpha channel, if any, is stripped from the output image" -- is that what you want? IMHO to handle "any possible supported type", I'd use `LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH` and then handle the various cases explicitly.

Comment: I updated the question... could you please check if this code is fail proof and I will always get CV_8UC4 images at the end. I have tested for some images and this worked. Please suggest any edit needed

Comment: Good work. I would add some handling for the case when `imread` fails to load an image (e.g. in the current program, since `filePath` is empty) and produce a meaningful error message. I would probably switch the order of the switches -- do the depth conversion first. It's a small optimization for the case where you change both depth and number of channels. This way, the intermediate array will require less memory. Finally it would be good to refactor it so you have a function that performs the conversion. Then write unit tests and cover all the cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I incorporated your suggestions into my code

Comment: I discovered there is a problem in using very large resolution images.... Is there an option to scale image while loading?

Comment: What kind of problem, and what size of images? Perhaps make a new question about that.

Comment: I made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286172/opencv-set-load-size-before-imread .... Could you please take a look and help me out