# OpenCV set load size before imread

Tags: opencv

I need to load an image in a cv::Mat and then resize it maintaining aspect ratio to a size smaller than screen size (1920x1080 in my case).

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read image file
cv::resize(image, image, cvSize(width, height)); //calculate width height separately
```

And after resizing I need to do further operations.

The problem is that I can use only 500 mb of memory and thus I cannot load image with very large resolution (of the order of 10k x 10k)

So, although I need to finally resize those images to smaller size (smaller than screen size) before operating further on them, I am not able to process very high resolution images.

Is there an option to scale the image while loading (reading file) so that cv::Mat uses memory according to the scaled version of the image and not the original size of the image?

Or, is there some other way in which I can load very high resolution images without using that much memory.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How about resizing them online? or using photoshop for example if it can load the image?

Comment: In OpenCV 3.x, a few more flags seem to have appeared ([`IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80a64063c4e6a917237bd2daef7aa23dc01) that allow you to do reduction by factor of 2, 4 or 8. While this won't do arbitrary scaling, it could allow you to load something more manageable. However, digging through the code, it seems only the JPEG decoder can use this directly -- in case of PNG, it will first load full-size and only then do a resize.

Comment: That said, libPNG isn't very complicated to use, and there are several methods on how to read row at a time, so with some effort you can implement something similar yourself. You could extend this to do arbitrary scaling that would use some circular row buffer to hold the necessary context, but that would be fairly involved to write (and write it well).